# Win 8 Freezes Randomly, Usually When Some Sort of Menu Is Open

Tags: windows-8, freeze

I've run into a really hard to troubleshoot issue: randomly (haven't found a reliable way to reproduce the issue, but happens frequently) on windows 8 pro x64, the computer freezes resulting in having to press the physical power off button to reboot.

It seems to happen the most reliably when I have some flavor of Firefox running (Cyberfox, Waterfox, Nightly (all are x64), and the 32 bit FF itself), but **not** always. I can sometimes run FF for a whole day w/out issue, then it just happens. It also seems to happen when I have a context-menu in **any** program up at the time, *BUT*, I've also seen it happen when I have the popup showing of a browser extension (i.e. a thumbnail zoom type of popup showing a larger version of an image I've hovered over).

Have done these so far w/no success:

```
• Updated Java (both x64 & x32)
• Updated all BIOS and Drivers
• Updated Adobe Flash Player (clean install)
• Updated GeForce Drivers (clean install)
• Installed all new matching RAM (and run extensive memtests)
• Uninstalled Avast and all other virus/malware software (after doing full scans first)
• Uninstalled the Image Resizer addon (has been reported to cause issues)
• Full uninstall of all Acronis products
• Run Hard Drive tests for errors both software and hardware
• Stopped the Daemon Tools service
• Tested with BIOS USB3 support enabled/disabled.
```

I'm perplexed at this point and out of time to figure this out, so I'm hoping some fresh minds will be able to pinpoint the issue. It's maddening! lol

---

@TheX : Yep, I've already run many different memory tests, including Memtest86+, it always tests healthy.

@paacharon3 : I have 16GB of G.Skil RAM, that almost never goes above about 7GB used, even with FF running and many, many tabs open, as well as Chrome open with many, many tabs open.

Yes, extensions like Facebook Zoom, I use Thumbnail Zoom Plus for FF though, and on Chrome I use Hover Zoom. I've had the PC freeze when an image was zoomed in the hover popup, but also have had it freeze when I have different context menu's up (meaning for example, if you were to right-click anywhere in just about any app and the menu pops up.)

Comment: Run Memtest86+ maybe? Bad RAM can cause all kinds of wonky issues...

Answer (score 0):

**Freezing problem issues**

**1 - Processing Speed/100% Cpu use -** This can be a potential issue. I have seen this in many PC, when the user uses multiple programs(Hi-Profile-Programs) simultaneously, then it freezes for some time and if you let it hang for a while then it will continue to work.

**2 - Faulty RAM -** This can be a problem but it comes with another issue, prolly its accomplish, THE BSOD. If you think you have seen screen freeze and then a BSOD or vice versa then change the RAM or clean it or do something.

**3 - Antivirus -** Trust me, Antivirus can be pretty annoying. Usually, silent automatic virus definition updates or scans could result in freezing of machine.

**4 - Bad HDD -** I think, as per your description, your HDD is failing. This is my personal experience and I have seen my 640 GB Toshiba HDD fail in front of my eyes and it hurts. What happens is when there is high disk write then it hangs and nothing seems to work, no ALT-CTRL-DEL, no key nothing. Except for holding the power button for a while to force shut it. Do check it with the some tools available online [LINK](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/tophddiag.htm). One more interesting thing that I needed to add is I used Windows 7 for a while and then I had to install Windows 8 cause the X drive got corrupted and then after a couple of days of use of windows 8 I saw that there is a warning message shown in the windows 8 that your HDD is failing. Please do check for that.

Nyways, I wasnot able to provide much help but atleast you know what to do now. Rush it to the service center.